# Find $E(X)$ from a PMF

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

I have a homework problem as follows.

$X =$ the leading digit of a randomly selected number from a large accounting ledger. The PMF for this random variable has been found to be defined by

$$P(X=x) = f(x)=\log_{10}\frac{x+1}{x},\;\;\;\;\; x=1,2,\dots,9.$$

> Find $E(X)$; round your answer to two decimal places.

I wrote code to calculate that:

```
E = 0
for (i in 1:9){
    P = i * log((i+1)/i, 10)
    E = E + P}
```

and got $3.44023696712321$ as the result; my final answer was $3.44$, but the system said it false.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: I can confirm your exact answer is correct. It says to round to two decimals - what if, instead of rounding your final answer, you round each time you take the log? (This gives 3.51, by the way.) If this answer passes, I will be extremely disappointed in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What could be wrong here? Well, the system that checks your answer could be wrong.

The answer $3.44$ is definitely the correct expected value of this random variable, which follows the well-known Benford's distribution. You can check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law#Moments) to confirm that it also gives an expected value of $3.440$ (to three digits after the decimal) for this distribution.

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem is in the grading system.